# Trunc date field in mysql like Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, date

I am to not able to use the 'trunc(in oracle)' function in 'mysql' database.  I have a table called dlb_cc_purchase and  date field called due_date in my 'mysql' database. The data displaying in the date field like `20-11-2014 00:00:00` (20-nov-2014). in oracle we are using query

```
select * from dlbcc_purchase where trunc(due_date) = '20-nov-2014'
```

Oracle DB will fetch the row with due date 20-11-2014 00:00:00. How can I use this function in 'mysql'?

I know this is a basic question, but i was trying to do this for long time with truncate, str_to_date... but not able to fetch value. Please help.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use [DATE(expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function. Query example:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dlbcc_purchase
  WHERE DATE(due_date) = '2014-11-20'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use **DATE_FORMAT()**.

***example:***

```
select * from dlbcc_purchase where DATE_FORMAT(due_date,'%d-%b-%Y') = '20-nov-2014'
```