# Less than date doesn't select equal date sql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

The where clause which I have:

```
r.completed <= '2017-01-12'
```

The r.completed (datetime) values are formatted as for example:

```
2017-01-06 14:48:29
```

This where clause doesn't select instances that are equal to the date given. How could I fix this problem? I have tried convert(datetime, '2017-01-12') but this gives an SQL error. DBMS is MySQL.

Comment: Please add your DBMS

Comment: What database? If it's Oracle then take a look at trunc() and apply that to the date with the timestamp in it

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Data type of `r.completed` is datetime

Comment: Is it possible to convert the right hand parameter as for example '2017-01-12 00:00:00' ?

Comment: DBMS is MySQL .

Comment: As per my previous comment, but since it is MySQL you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322398/trunc-date-field-in-mysql-like-oracle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use

```
CAST(r.completed as DATE) <='2017-01-12'
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my problem :-). Will accept the answer when I am allowed to!

Comment: @Anna Jeanine You can accept. Please visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 6):

The date `2017-01-12` is translated to `2017-01-12 00:00:00`

So a value like `2017-01-12 14:48:29` is greater than `2017-01-12 00:00:00`.

If you want to match also this particular day you would have to use `r.completed < '2017-01-13'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to inlcude all time of the given date

```
r.completed < '2017-01-13'
```

The above will include all date before start of 2017-01-13